# Perl HTTPS 443 error

Tags: perl, https

My Perl script works on PCs. However, when I ran it on a Windows Server 2003 server, it gave me:

> https 443 error (500 can't connect to "the website":443).

My script uses `LWP:UserAgent` to download a file from an HTTPS address. Here what I did so far:

1. I tested connecting other HTTPS addresses on that server, and they worked.
2. I tried setting `$ENV{PERL_LWP_SSL_VERIFY_HOSTNAME} = 0`, but it was not working.
3. I tried `Mozilla::CA` and `CACertOrg::CA`, but it was not working; I also tried setting `$ENV{HTTPS_CA_FILE}= "path to the downloaded CA file"`, but it was not working.

Here goes my partial original script:

```
sub retrieveHTTPS {
    my ($url, $encrypted_file) = @_;
    use LWP::UserAgent;
    my $browser = LWP::UserAgent->new;
    my $response =
    $browser->get($url, ':content_file' => $encrypted_file);
    die "Error at $url\n ", $response->status_line, "\n Aborting"
            unless $response->is_success;}
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Do you mean 403? What's in your error log?

Comment: error message is 500 can't connect to "...": 443

Comment: Please add the *complete* error message.

Comment: Also, put the `use LWP::UserAgent` at the top of the file so you have all your dependencies in one place. The `use`d module is loaded at compile time. That means, it will not be loaded when the sub is called only. It will always be loaded when the file is first compiled.

Answer (score 0):

From the LWP::UserAgent documentation:

> The libwww-perl core no longer bundles protocol plugins for SSL. You
>   will need to install LWP::Protocol::https separately to enable support
>   for processing https-URLs.

There's a good chance that you don't have the requisite modules installed on your Windows Server 2003 server to support HTTPS.

Try installing LWP::Protocol::https.

It's also a good idea to add `use LWP::Protocol::https;` to your script to make this dependency explicit.

Comment: Actually I've done this but not working though...still thank you.

Comment: OK. LWP::Protocol::https then uses Net:HTTPS which in turn uses IO::Socket::SSL or Net::SSL. Its also worthwhile checking whic of these are installed and which versions they're at.