# Simple perl script doesn't work with itorrents API (12 LINES)

Tags: api, perl, ide, send, torrent

yesterday i tried to code an example script with perl and itorrents api, i'm using the perl IDE Padre. Basically, this script sends data to a server (itorrents) here's the link of the api: itorrents.org/automation i copied and pasted the code that the website gived to me, and it's not working!
I installed this perl modules with windows cmd:

```
cpan App:cpanminus
cpanm MIME::Base64
cpanm MIME::Parser
cpanm MIME::Tools
cpanm Test::XML
cpanm SOAP::Lite
cpanm SOAP::WSDL
```

This is my script (caching.pl):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
    
use MIME::Base64 ();
use SOAP::Lite ();
    
open( FILE, 'my.torrent' ) or die "$!";
while( read( FILE, $buf, 60*57 ) ) { $tor .= MIME::Base64::encode( $buf ); }
close( FILE );
    
$infoHash = SOAP::Lite->service( 'http://itorrents.org/api/torrage.wsdl' )->cacheTorrent( $tor );
    
print $infoHash;
```

Thanks in advance, im not fluent in this language, sorry.
Edit: sorry i forget to post the error line:

```
Service description 'http://itorrents.org/api/torrage.wsdl' can't be loaded: 500 Can't connect to itorrents.org:443
```

Comment: Can you please explain in a bit more detail what is not working? Are you getting error messages? Any output at all?  // There's a typo in your first code block, `SOAP:Lite` should be `SOAP::Lite`, so that wouldn't have installed. This example is also not very high quality code.

Comment: `http://itorrents.org/api/torrage.wsdl` redirects to `https://itorrents.org/api/torrage.wsdl`. (301 Moved Permanently. You should use the HTTPS version directly.) You were apparently able to fetch `http://itorrents.org/api/torrage.wsdl` since the error mentions port 443 (the HTTPS port). But for some reason, you are unable to connect to `https://itorrents.org/api/torrage.wsdl`.

Comment: I don't know why you can't connect to the the HTTPS service on the same host, but it could be an outdated library. I had the same problem recently. I don't know which module/library I had to update since I just switched to a newer `perl` I already had installed.

Comment: What Perl version do you have? `perl -v` to check. Is it Strawberry Perl, ActiveState Perl, or something else? Which version of Windows? Is perl on port 443 allowed through your firewall? Do you have Net::SSLeay, LWP::Protocol::https, or IO::Socket::SSL installed? Your script works out of the box (without needing to install anything from CPAN) on Strawberry Perl 5.32.1.1 64-bit. Also works fine in WSL after installing `libopenssl-devel` and Net::SSLeay. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13612683/perl-https-443-error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved !** I solved it downloading the torrage.wsdl file from http://itorrents.org/api/torrage.wsdl and replaced this line:

```
$infoHash = SOAP::Lite->service( 'http://itorrents.org/api/torrage.wsdl' )->cacheTorrent( $tor );
```

With this line(replacing the website URL with the downloaded file torrage.wsdl path):

```
$infoHash = SOAP::Lite->service( 'file:///C:/Users/sussq/Desktop/perl2exe/torrage.wsdl' )->cacheTorrent( $tor );
```

For more information and explanation see this post: [SOAP::Lite can't connect to host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70811664/soaplite-cant-connect-to-host)