# SOAP::Lite can't connect to host

Tags: perl

Yesterday I tried to do a script that sends data to a website but I encountered a strange error that [I solved](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70813526/2766176):

I installed this perl modules with windows cmd(not in order):

```
cpanm MIME::Base64
cpanm MIME::Parser
cpanm MIME::Tools
cpanm Test::XML
cpanm SOAP::Lite
cpanm SOAP::WSDL
cpan App::cpanminus
```

This was my old script (caching.pl):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use MIME::Base64 ();

use SOAP::Lite ();

open( FILE, 'my.torrent' ) or die "$!";

while( read( FILE, $buf, 60*57 ) ) { $tor .= MIME::Base64::encode( $buf ); }
close( FILE );

$infoHash = SOAP::Lite->service( 'http://itorrents.org/api/torrage.wsdl' )->cacheTorrent( $tor );

print $infoHash;
```

And I encountered this error (that I solved):

```
Service description 'http://itorrents.org/api/torrage.wsdl' can't be loaded: 500 Can't connect to itorrents.org:443
```

I solved by downloading the torrage.wsdl from http://itorrents.org/api/torrage.wsdl and I replaced this line (of old caching.pl script):

```
$infoHash = SOAP::Lite->service( 'http://itorrents.org/api/torrage.wsdl' )->cacheTorrent( $tor );
```

With this line (instead of the torrage.wsdl located in the website I tried replacing it with my pc path of where the torrage.wsdl file that I downloaded was):

```
$infoHash = SOAP::Lite->service( 'C:\Users\sussq\Desktop\perl2exe\torrage.wsdl' )->cacheTorrent( $tor );
```

But now i encounter this error:

```
Service description 'C:\Users\sussq\Desktop\perl2exe\torrage.wsdl' can't be loaded: 501 Protocol scheme 'c' is not supported
```

Can anyone know how to solve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question is unclear. What does this have to do with [tag:scheme]?

Comment: @Jörg W Mittag, It was surely meant as a reference to URI schemes (`http:`, `ftp:`, `file:`, `data:`, etc)

Comment: When you run into problems like this, check that you can connect in an interactive browser. You answered that this host is banned in your region, so you should have seen a similar error. That way you know it's not Perl's fault.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The definition of the `service()` method that you call is given in [the documentation for SOAP::Lite](https://metacpan.org/pod/SOAP::Lite) as:

> **service(service URL)**
>
> ```
> $client->service('http://svc.perl.org/Svc.wsdl');
> ```

So the argument that you need to pass into the method is a URL - the address of the WSDL file.

Initially, you pass it the URL - http://itorrents.org/api/torrage.wsdl. But for some reason that doesn't work (from your answer, it seems you've got to the bottom of that problem).

So you saved the WSDL file locally and passed the location of the local file to the method. That doesn't work as 'C:\Users\sussq\Desktop\perl2exe\torrage.wsdl' is not a valid URL.

The first part of a URL (the bit before the colon) is the 'protocol'. That means it defines the mechanism used to retrieve this resource. In a web-based URL, that's either 'http' or 'https'. The local path that you try to pass to the method rates with 'c:', so the method thinks that's a protocol. But it's not one that it knows about, so you get your error message.

There is a mechanism for building URLs to local files. It's called the [file:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme) protocol. I'm no expert on Windows, but I think your URL should be:

```
file:///C:/Users/sussq/Desktop/perl2exe/torrage.wsdl
```

Comment: Re "*I'm no expert on Windows, but I think your URL should be:*", One used have to use `C|` instead of `C:`, but I don't think that's the case anymore. This seems supported by the fact that URI::file keeps the `:` when transforming a path into a URI. Whether allowed or not, I'm sure LWP (and thus SOAP::Lite) doesn't care.

Comment: @ikegami: The Wikipedia article that I link to says this - "On Microsoft Windows systems, the normal colon (:) after a device letter has sometimes been replaced by a vertical bar (|) in file URLs. This reflected the original URL syntax, which made the colon a reserved character in a path part."

Answer (score 3):

A URI is expected, and

```
C:\Users\sussq\Desktop\perl2exe\torrage.wsdl
```

isn't one. One could use

```
file:///C:/Users/sussq/Desktop/perl2exe/torrage.wsdl
```

But what if we didn't want to hardcode an absolute path? We could use the following:

```perl
use Cwd       qw( abs_path );
use FindBin   qw( $RealBin );
use URI::file qw( );

my $uri = URI::file->new( abs_path( "$RealBin/torrage.wsdl" ) )->as_string;
```

This would look for `torrage.wsdl` in the same directory as the script.